# Asterisk Realtime configuration issue

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to configure Asterisk for real time communication with a MySql database. After all the configurations, I am getting the following error when I run the command `sip show peeers`:

```
[Nov 11 01:52:58] WARNING[14698]: config.c:2289 find_engine: Realtime mapping for 'sippeers' found to engine 'mysql', but the engine is not available
```

I have also installed the add-ons but it is still not able to run : realtime mysql status, command. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1) Stop the current running asterisk instance.
2) Go the the asterisk install directory, do menuselect and  enable the following addons:
    A) app_mysql
    B) cdr_mysql
    C) res_config_mysql
3) make
4) make install

Give correct credentials in res_config_mysql.conf for asterisk to connect to mysql.
This is tested for asterisk 11.14.1

Answer (score 0):

You need check that you have res_mysql.so in your libs directories.

Also you need check configuration /etc/asterisk/res_config.conf exists and valid.